# C-< and C-, keys are echoed as C-\ in no-window mode

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, terminal-emacs, multiple-cursors

I'm trying to edit multiple lines with `multiple-cursors` package. MC package has `C-<` keybinding but when I do `C-<` (Control+less-than sign) it is echoed as `C-\` (Control+backslash).

I don't know how to solve it. The same applies to `C-,` (Control+comma) as well. I activate MC with `C-S-c C-S-c` (Control+Shift+c Control+Shift+c) keybinding.

I can share my code if that will help.

Edit 1: My OS is MS Windows 10 and emacs is 25.2.1.

Comment: Do you see a similar problem with Emacs in general, or only when you use multiple-cursors? If the former then this sounds like it might be a problem that's outside Emacs. What does Emacs tell you when you use `C-h k` and then you type `C-<` or `C-,`?

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the problem. If you do, then it sounds like it's a problem with your Emacs or your platform. In that case you could try `M-x report-emacs-bug` (providing a recipe from `emacs -Q`).

Comment: On what operating system? GUI or terminal-based Emacs? Some operating systems and especially some terminals report some Control+character keys in strange ways.

Comment: Hi, everybody. And thanks for helping me. It seems that the problem arises when I run 'emacs -nw' (emacs no-window). I was able to see the echo via 'C-h k' (describe key). My OS is MS Windows 10, my emacs is 25.2.1. I see that 'C-<' and 'C-,' are echoed as themselves when I run emacs graphically (or GUI or in X-mode, I don't know what it is called exactly), but I love no-window mode. I don't like how the terminal is also left open when I run emacs GUI. Thanks everybody, again.

Comment: @Drew problem arises in emacs in general. Thanks.

Comment: @Gilles in terminal-based emacs not GUI. In GUI the key bindings are echoed as themselves. Windows 10 is my OS. Thanks.

Comment: If those keys are not available when you use Emacs in terminal mode then bind other keys to those commands.

Comment: @Drew OK, thanks. It's not big issue since I learned that I can handle it in GUI. Shall we close this question or leave it open for answers, what do you think community? Thanks, again.

Comment: What terminal are you using? I didn't know Emacs had a terminal mode on Windows.

Comment: @Gilles I do 'windows key + r' and then write there "cmd" there opens something called "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" and there I write "emacs -nw" to open emacs no-window mode, but if I write only emacs then emacs GUI opens, and moreover, that cmd terminal (or other name, I don't know its name in Windows) is also left open. When, in GUI mode, I close either of emacs GUI or cmd terminal, both of them closes (or quits). Thanks.

Comment: I see, thanks. I didn't know this was possible on Windows. I have no idea if it's possible to change how control keys work there.

Comment: @Gilles OK, no problem. You made me so happy, already. I'm so happy that I know something that a professional like you just learned. Don't take offense, please. I'm not intending to hurt you, I only want to express my happiness. Thank you, dear moderator and brother. By the way, I know that there is an ocean of knowledge that I don't possess but you do ;)